# Excel: Export to XML - With XML in cells

Tags: excel, xml

I'm trying to export a spreadsheet that has some XML in some of the cells of the table.

ID (column A): 23455

FACT (column B) (this code is copied & pasted from a sample cell - they don't all have this simplicity or structure):

```
"<div class=""fact"">
<p><strong>FACT.</strong> The closest star to our solar system is Alpha Centauri.</p>
</div>
"
```

I'd like to have XML like the following:

```
<record>
    <ID>23455</ID>
    <FACT><div class="fact"><p><strong>FACT.</strong> The closest star to our solar system is Alpha Centauri.</p></div></FACT>
</record>
```

This is complex enough that I doubt that Excel's native XML schema export will work (that thing is persnickety enough that I can't get it to work with simplest of data values).

My current thought is to write a Perl script, to read this as a CSV file and export XML. However, I've noticed that CSV does a poor job handling XML that's been "embedded" like this.

I'm hoping someone else might have a better suggestion for how to pull this information out.

---

Edit: Finally figured out the mistake I made with export. Can export and get the following:

```
<record>
    <ID>23455</ID>
    <FACT>&lt;div class="fact"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;FACT.&lt;/strong&gt; The closest star to our solar system is Alpha Centauri.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt
    </FACT>
</record>
```

I think I can work with this...some regex and it might be good enough (looking for all `&lt;` might put me at risk of killing a true less-than sign).

So I'm still open to suggestions

Comment: This statement should go for the best statement made this year!: "My current thought is to write a Perl script, to read this as a CSV file and export XML. However, I've noticed that CSV does a poor job handling XML that's been "embedded" like this."

Comment: A suggestion could be, if you want to stick to EXCEL, is create a macro.

Comment: @Luuk - This vendor loves to give us csv flies with embedded xml. Nearly every file ends up "corrupted" about half way through when it starts creating new rows and columns at "random" (I know the program has it's reasons). It completely kills any hope of working with the data within Excel. I've tried before with perl - it's also miserable. As annoying as messing up legit less-than/greater-than signs would be, regex in XML would bring fewer tears and cursing.

Comment: Wow, I wish my employer has a vendor who supplied csv files with embedded xml.... I would resign (almost) immediately.  (Because CSV is not a good file format for doing that kind of stuff.....)

Comment: @Luuk - my project gets one better. Vendor A gave us csv with HTML (technically). I'm "good with Excel" and so was drafted into transforming it into an import spreadsheet for Vendor B (also with HTML included). They said it would be stuff like "repeating columns". Instead I have to parse the HTML and split it out into columns.

Hence the "how do I get it out to deal with this in XSLT/perl" - soon to be asking "how do I get this back into Excel?" But one problem at a time.

Comment: You migh be better of asking the question "How can I transform this HTML to XML") (Complete with an example of HTML and XML),   But unfortunately for you SO is not a code-writing service... .  I really doubt that EXCEL is a good tool to do that sort of things.

Comment: If you add your attempts of the perl script, you could even add the `perl` tag. Which makes it a good question on SO... 

Comment: @Luuk - nope! I tried it about a year ago using Perl - no way I'm trying that again! But thanks for the suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this as the answer...

If you export the column as text you can get the following:

```
<record>
    <ID>23455</ID>
    <FACT>&lt;div class="fact"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;FACT.&lt;/strong&gt; The closest star to our solar system is Alpha Centauri.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt
    </FACT>
</record>
```

In an XML editor I did a find and replace to get all the tags using the following regex: `s/&lt;(\/?[\w\s="-_]+?)&gt;/<$1>/`

It's a bit dangerous if there are actual signs in the document, but you'd need a case where it was `< /maybe and text with common tag symbols ="-_ >` - possible but most equations are of the form `X < Y < Z`. Our content doesn't use <> all that much, so I can be fairly confident it won't catch the edge case.

I also "fixed" all the HTML (`s/<b>/<b/>/` and `s/<img (.*?)>/<img $1/>/`) and checked parsing (theoretically an edge case would cause a parsing error).

And yes, I now have a doc in mixed DTD that will make all true XML peeps quake with horror, but I can work with it.

Comment: "I know have"... should be "I now have"  (English is also not my first language)

Comment: @Luuk Thanks! English is my first language, but mistakes happen.